# Issue with cut command

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sh

I'm having issues with the cut command,

This is an example of the original file:

```
userid1:john doe smith:group1
userid2:jane doe smith:group2
userid3:paul rudd :group2
```

The expected result:

```
userid1
userid2
userid3
```

Testing command:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
id=`id -u`
if [ $id -eq 0 ]

for i in `cat users.txt`
do
userid=`echo $i|cut -d":" -f1`

echo "$userid" >>temp.txt
`chmod 777 temp.txt`
done
```

This gives me this output:

```
userid1
doe
smith
userid2
doe
smith
userid3
rudd
```

If I erase the space between the name and last name, it works, and I'm specifying ":" as delimiter, dunno what I'm missing.

How can I get the expected result?

Cheers.

UPDATE: Fixed changing for loop to while...read.

Comment: Maybe `sed 's/:.*//' < your_file`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your bash script.

```
 for i in `cat users.txt`
```

The above line splits your text up by spaces. Just do:

```
cut -d":" -f1 < users.txt >>temp.txt
chmod 777 temp.txt
```

If for some reason you bash to process each line individually (perhaps because you need to do something with the userid rather than just output it), you can use `read` as in the following:

```
while read i 
do
userid=`echo $i|cut -d":" -f1`

echo "$userid" >>temp.txt
chmod 777 temp.txt
done < users.txt
```

Comment: This works, but it generates many iterations, im using for because it is a long file and I need to prepare the structure to use with newusers. Since the issue is with FOR, I think I may need to use IFS.

Comment: @RexApplegate I am not sure what you mean by many iterations. It only calls cut once; it should also be a lot faster than your code.

Comment: I mean i need to do this for many users, not only 3, so I need to use a loop, I'm trying with IFS but is not working either.

Comment: @RexApplegate I don't understand. Why do you need to use a loop just because you have many users? It is not like cut needs to load the whole file into memory.

Comment: Because I need to prepare a file with the wrong structure to later use with newusers, so in order to automatize the task, im trying to loop said file, restructure the content and then use newusers. I got the result I wanted changing from for to while... read, so I'm gonna, mark it as solved and keep working to get the final result, Thanks.